# Splash Images in iOS 7 with XCode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

Every thing is going fine. Just one issue with Launch Images in iOS7 with XCode 5 by using Asset Catalogue.

In my iPad App, i have splash images of all the sizes.

When i am selecting Portrait Non-Retina [768x1024], its added successfully; after that when i select Portrait Retina [1536x2048], then Non-Retina [768x1024] image removed and giving this error "No image with correct dimensions found". Vise Versa is also applying.

Same behavior is for Landscape Retina and Non-Retina images.

Please suggest any solution. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: By the way, you are **not** using Asset Catalog. Which is a lot more convenient and simple, believe me.

Comment: Make sure that your portrait is correct dimensions, that also means that it is 768x1024, not 1024x768!

Comment: Hit the button that says "use asset catalog" it's much easier to add images and manage everything that way.

Comment: Thanks All; Its working now. Issue was that, images were not there in asset catalog. I was supposing, it will automatically copied in asset catalog after adding and clicking on Asset Catalog button. As i add it manually, its working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have investigated, how we can use Asset Catalog; Now it seems to be easy for me. I want to show you steps to add icons and splash in asset catalog.

**Note:** No need to make any entry in info.plist file :) And no any other configuration.

In below image, at right side, you will see highlighted area, where you can mention which icons you need. In case of mine, i have selected first four checkboxes; As its for my app requirements. You can select choices according to your requirements.

[image]

Now, see below image. As you will select any App icon then you will see its detail at right side selected area. It will help you to upload correct resolution icon.
[image]

If Correct resolution image will not be added then following warning will come. Just upload the image with correct resolution.
[image]

After uploading all required dimensions, you shouldn't get any warning.
[image]

Comment: This still works as of iOS 8 and iPhone 6 & iPhone 6 Plus. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Delete the image from the asset catalogue and copy it back again. Perform and Clean and then build. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually use asset catalog by clicking the asset catalog button. Then you will get templates specifying every size you need, and you can drag and drop or import you PNGs and see where you're missing images or the size is wrong. In asset catalog, clicking on the properties pane for an image will show you the size of the image it expects, and teh size you gave it, so you can easily see any discrepancies.